# Uber Sandbox Request call giving : internal_server_error

Tags: javascript, rest

I am trying to call request[sandbox] but get the below error:

```
{"message":"We have experienced a problem.","code":"internal_server_error"}
```

This is a POST call.

url : https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/?scope=request

header: `Authorization: Bearer access_token`

body:

```
{
  "start_latitude": "startlat",
  "start_longitude": "startlng",
  "end_latitude": "endlat",
  "end_longitude": "endlng",
  "product_id": "productId"
}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

URL was not correct!!! "My Mistake"

But i am getting new error :

> {\"message\":\"Only request header `Content-Type: application\\/json`
>   is supported for this endpoint. Please check your request
>   headers.\",\"code\":\"invalid_content_type\"}
>
> headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
>   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }

I am passing Content-Type in Headers but still it is giving the same error :(